# How to input text from a swing on screen keyboard to another swing JFrame

Tags: swing, keyboard, jframe, awt, jtextfield

[image: 2 frames]

I have a swing on screen keyboard that can be used to send key presses to the other JFrame but it is not focusing on the JTextField.

Should I put jtextfield.requestfocus in every key so it should work?

Note:

The Input JFrame calls the keyboard Swing and passes the JTextField instance for focus request

Comment: Did you try putting jtextfield.requestfocus in to see  hat happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your keyboard frame you can use:

```
frame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
```

This should prevent the window from receiving focus to focus will remain on the other window.